# Solving Combinatorics Problem

Tags: combinations

How many different basketball teams can be formed from a squad of 12 men if only 2 of the men can play center and these two can play in no other position?

My answer is

$N$= $10C4$ $\cdot$ $2C1$ = $420$ teams

Comment: How many ways can you choose a center? How many ways can you choose the other four players? Multiply these two numbers.

Comment: 10C4 x 2C1 is this correct?

Comment: @Madisson It's not about whether you got to the answer - it's about **how** you got to the answer. Please show your work and put it in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $12$ player, in particular $10$ of them can play everywhere while $2$ have a fixed position.
First we do all the calculation considering only $1$ center and finally we are going to multiply by $2$ our partial results.

We know that each team is made of $5$ people. We fix the one who must play as a center and we have $\binom{10}{4}$ possibility to choose the other four player. This means that, at the end, we have:
$$\binom{10}{4}\cdot 2=210\cdot 2=420$$
possible teams.